# How to use Ionic 2's config api?

Tags: ionic2

I do not understand how to use the config api that is listed here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/config/Config/

Particularly this example below:

```
config.set('ios', 'favoriteColor', 'green');
// from any page in your app:
config.get('favoriteColor'); // 'green' when iOS
```

What are my imports? Can I do this in the `app.module.ts`? Also, the documents read that if I don't say the platform then the variable is available on all platforms, what would the syntax look like then?
`config.set(null, 'appName', 'App')`? `config.set('appName', 'App')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My man from Ghana answered this:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,
    {
      mode: 'ios',
      fav: 'red'
    })
  ],
```

And then from anywhere else:

```
import { NavController, Config } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController
  , public config: Config
  ) {
    this.temp = this.config.get('fav');
  }
```